# Error: Compile Error: A non foreign key field cannot be referenced in a path expression

Tags: trigger

I have an apex trigger that involves querying multiple objects. But I encounter this kind of error :

> Error: Compile Error: A non foreign key field cannot be referenced in
>   a path expression: ObjectBs__r

Here's a portion of the trigger where I encounter such error message:

```
Set<Id> objAid = new Set<Id>(); 
Set<Id> objDid = new Set<Id>();

for(ObjectC__c c : Trigger.new) {
        objAid.add(c.ObjectA__c);   
}

List<ObjectA__c> objAList = [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name, ObjectD__c FROM ObjectBs__r) FROM ObjectA__c WHERE Id IN: objAid];

for(ObjectA__c a : objAList[0].ObjectBs__r) {
        objDid.add(a.ObjectBs__r.ObjectD__c);
}
```

Comment: Does `ObjectB__c` have a relationship (master-detail, or lookup) to `ObjectA__c`? If it does, are you certain that `ObjectBs__r` is the correct child relationship name? (you can check by going to the detail page for the relationship field and looking for "child relationship name")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ObjectBs__r` in this case is a relationship name. When you perform a SOQL query that includes a subquery, as you do in this case:

```
[SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name, ObjectD__c FROM ObjectBs__r) FROM ObjectA__c WHERE Id IN: objAid]
```

where `(SELECT Id, Name, ObjectD__c FROM ObjectBs__r)` is the subquery, you can treat the property `ObjectBs__r` as a `List<ObjectB__c>` in your Apex code.

The issue here is that you are indexing *through* `a.ObjectBs__r.ObjectD__c` as if `ObjectBs__c` were a lookup field containing the Id of a single `ObjectB__c` (a foreign key).

I'm not 100% confident of your data model based on the description given, but it looks to me like

```
objDid.add(a.ObjectBs__r.ObjectD__c);
```

should just be

```
objDid.add(a.ObjectD__c);
```

since `a` already comes from the `ObjectBs__r` list. `a` may also be declared as the wrong type in your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(ObjectA__c a : objAList[0].ObjectBs__r) {
        objDid.add(a.ObjectBs__r.ObjectD__c);
}
```

Problem is here.

You're trying iterate over ObjectBs__r but you're delcaring a as ObjectA__c.

```
for(ObjectB__c a : objAList[0].ObjectBs__r) {
        objDid.add(a.Id);
}
```

Comment: This is a good catch. It's certainly _an_ error, but I think this would generate a `loop variable expected type <x>` type error rather than the one OP is currently running in to.