# A non foreign key field cannot be referenced in a path expression: BH_US_Delivery_Engagement__c

Tags: apex, salesforce-id

I have a lookup on Veeva events object for delivery engagement with API name BH_US_Delivery_Engagement__c.
When I am trying to access it on my code getting the above error. Can anyone help ?

Also, PFA the screenshot.[image]

Comment: please edit your question to add the code instead of an image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Compile Error: A non foreign key field cannot be referenced in a path expression](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/209592/error-compile-error-a-non-foreign-key-field-cannot-be-referenced-in-a-path-exp)

Answer (score 1):

Since,you are trying to call the related Object please try by using __r instead of __c for the related Object "BH_US_Delivery_Engagement__c".

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is you are trying to access the field value of the parent object record with the field API name of the lookup field.

> When you use a relationship name in a query, you must use the
> relationship names without the __c. Instead, append an __r (underscore
> underscore r).

**ev.BH_US_Delivery_Engagement__c** itself returns you the id of the delivery engagement selected on veeva event record.

If you want to access it from BH_US_Delivery_Engagement__c record, You need to relationship name of the lookup field. You should do it using:- **ev.BH_US_Delivery_Engagement__r.Id**

To make it more clear for you, see the below image:-
[image]

- When you use a child-to-parent relationship, you can use dot notation:-

`SELECT Id, FirstName__c, Mother_of_Child__r.FirstName__c FROM Daughter__c WHERE Mother_of_Child__r.LastName__c LIKE 'C%'`

This query returns the ID and first name of daughter objects, and the first name of the daughter's mother if the mother's last name begins with 'C.'

Read more here:- [Understanding Relationship Names, Custom Objects, and Custom Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm)